# Is ADBD source code part of the kernel or AOSP?

Tags: adb

Is the ADBd (ADB Daemon) source code part of the kernel or AOSP (Android Open Source Project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't checked the source, but I believe it's part of AOSP. Though, being a system application, it does have special permissions that are unobtainable on unrooted device by installed applications.